# Read only one cellvalue of an excel using POI HSSF API

Tags: java, performance, excel-2010

[image]

I have to read only one column from the excel say the column is "C4" the value is **280000**

I have used apache POI .

I iterated each row and each column and checked the value and I get the answer.

Is there any other shortcut to get the value .

My code is

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(3);
            for (int columnCount = 0; columnCount < 13; columnCount++)
            {
              Cell  cell = row.getCell(columnCount);
             if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
                    {
                      switch (columnCount)
                        {
                            case 2:
                                System.out.println("Value "+cell.getStingCellValue());
                                break;
                         }
                     }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You serious? You wrote a loop you know you don't need? So remove it:

```
Row row = sheet.getRow(3);
Cell  cell = row.getCell(2);
if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {
    System.out.println("Value "+cell.getStingCellValue());
}
```